# How to use ItemTouchHelper and its Callback or implement customized ones?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-support-design

I noticed these libraries and was eager to use them in my app.
My `RecyclerView` uses `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to organize `viewHolders` and I've written down the following code:

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END,
            ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                              RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            mAdapter.move(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mAdapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

There are two problems:

1. Swiping an item won't change its `alpha` by `deltaX`.
2. Imagine that there are 3 items in the `RecyclerView` (which has 2 columns):

   - the first is a middle-size one;
   - the second is smaller than the first one;
   - the third is the biggest.

If I move the third one to the first place, scroll the `RecyclerView` down (other items won't influence the first 3 ones) and then up, the second one and the third one will be totally the same.

It seems that I should write a customized `ItemTouchHelper` to add `alpha` animation to solve the first problem and that I didn't use these classes correctly and thus caused the second problem.

As a result, what is the best sample for using `ItemTouchHelper`? Or how to implement a customized one? Thanks in advance for any answers or comments.

Comment: A google search led me to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30644208/1326147 where those are being used.

Comment: @Armfoot sorry for not showing what I really need before. I read that answer before and knew how to use a SimpleCallback for ItemTouchHelper. However, in fact, I want to know how to implement a customized ItemTouchHelper and its Callback. Sorry again.

Comment: no problem, then please edit your question (title and body) referring exactly that "how to implement a customized ItemTouchHelper and its Callback: more people may help if you show you have done some research on the topic and tried to do something about it yourself.

Comment: @Armfoot Thanks for your suggestions and I improved my questions. Is it clear now? I don't have enough reputation to show any pictures so that I described my problem as accurate as I could.

Comment: Your question is clear now, specially the examples you provided will help much better, nicely done! (upvted)

Comment: @Armfoot Thank you very much!!! I will follow your improvements at any questions I ask in the future.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments in `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` you want to override the methods `onChildDraw` or `onChildDrawOver` for those dX, dY values.

Also see `getDefaultUIUtil` and the implementations of `ItemTouchUIUtil` (which is what `onChildDraw` and `onChildDrawOver` call). The comment of `getDefaultUIUtil` demonstrates how to use it in conjunction with overriding `onChildDraw` and `onChildDrawOver` (even though the examples erroneously return a bool value for being handled).

Here's a quick example if you want to add 5 to the default elevation in Lollipop:

```
    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && isCurrentlyActive && !isElevated) {
            final float newElevation = 5f + ViewCompat.getElevation(viewHolder.itemView);
            ViewCompat.setElevation(viewHolder.itemView, newElevation);
            isElevated = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        isElevated = false;
    }
```

Comment: Lollipop's ItemTouchUIUtil already does it, but somehow, shadow is not drawn :(