# Drag And drop in Recycler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[Drag and drop items in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901044/drag-and-drop-items-in-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager)

here the views int he grid are swapped. Is it possible to create a clone of a view and make it a duplicate entry in the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

make your "duplicated" view in a separate Fragment. Check [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) for more info.