# Recyclerview Drag and Drop ontouch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have used `ItemTouchHelper` to implement drag and drop in `recyclerview`. It works fine. But it is working only on long press. I need to do it with `onTouch`

```
ItemTouchHelper.Callback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        Collections.swap(strings, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        //TODO
    }

   //defines the enabled move directions in each state (idle, swiping, dragging).
     @Override
     public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
         return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG,
             ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END);
         }
    };
```

This is the code I used. Please help me!!!

Comment: you can check out this example....https://www.journaldev.com/23208/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop

Comment: You can look at this solution I've made: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204561/878126

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Override `ItemTouchHelper`'s `isLongPressDragEnabled` and return false

   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#isLongPressDragEnabled()

   `override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean = false`
2. Add a callback to ViewHolder's implementation and use this

   ```
   buttonToDrag.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
       listener.onTouch(this, event)
       false
   }
   ```
3. In the activity or fragment, use `startDrag`

   ```
   private lateinit var itemTouchHelper: ItemTouchHelper

   override fun onTouch(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, event: MotionEvent) {
       if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           itemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder)
       }
   }
   ```

I found the implementation in the doc of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper#startdrag

I've tried it personally and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code inside onBindViewHolder to start drag by touch

```
holder.layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return false;
    }
});
```

layout mean your item layout. after you can use DragListener for the all other events, like

```
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED
DragEvent.ACTION_DROP
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED
```