# Animate GridView item movement from one cell to another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

Can anyone give me a solution to animate `GridView / RecyclerView` item movement from one cell to another cell? I didn't find a solution to move it out of the bounded cell.

[image]

*Please don't mark the question as duplicate if you didn't understand the question correctly as I have searched over SOF before asking*

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901044/drag-and-drop-items-in-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager