# How to swap from one LinearLayout to another LinearLayout using drag and drop framework in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-linearlayout, swap

I have `TextView` and `ImageView` in one `LinearLayout`. I want to drag first `LinearLayout` to second `LinearLayout` in such a manner when I drop the first linear to second `LinearLayout`, its `TextView` and `ImageView` should come in first `LinearLayout` and vice versa. I have done the R&D where I have found to drag and drop layout from first to second but the second layout is not coming in the first layout.

The problem is the layouts are not getting an exchange. I am able to drag and drop from first to second but unable to do first to second.

Below is my fragment :

```java
public class MoreDestinationFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener, View.OnDragListener {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private LinearLayout llNews;

    public MoreDestinationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more_destination, container, false);

        llNews = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_new);

        llNews.setOnClickListener(this);
        llNews.setOnTouchListener(this);
        llNews.setOnDragListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.ll_new:
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_moreDestinationFragment_to_newsDestinationFragment);
                break;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d("xxxxxxx", "Drag event started");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d("xxxxxxx", "Drag event entered into " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d("xxxxxxx", "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d("xxxxxxx", "Dropped");
                View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d("xxxxxxx", "Drag ended");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Please help me out and please advice the solution. Thanks.

Comment: [Why don't you use `RecyclerView` with `ItemTouchHelper`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29901044/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod I'm not getting how it will be helpful for me :(

Comment: Check out the link in an above comment or just search  `ItemTouchHelper` in google

Comment: @NileshRathod With the help of `ItemTouchHelper` we can do drag, drop and swipe or dismiss but exchange the view is not possible means vice versa.

Comment: Yes that is possible but you have create logic for that functionality

Comment: I'm unable to do that that's why I"m asking a question na :)

Comment: @A.R. If you never mind to do it with RecyclerView, I can let you know if you wish.

Comment: @A.R. does my answer make sense? your feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this with `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` instead of
>   several `LinearLayout`'s as below:

**Steps:**

**Add below dependencies into gradle app module**

```
// RecyclerView
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

// CardView
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

**Main Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**List item layout** (of the RecyclerView)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:background="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="Android" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Model class for items to be populated in RecyclerView**

```
public class Item {

   private String mTitle;
    private int mThumbnail;

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public Item(String title, int thumbnail) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        mThumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.mTitle = title;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return mThumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        mThumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Item> mItems;

    public Adapter(ArrayList items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindViews(mItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTitle;
        ImageView mThumbnail;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            mThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imThumbnail);
        }

        void bindViews(Item item) {
            mTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
            mThumbnail.setImageResource(item.getThumbnail());
        }
    }
}
```

**And finally the main behavior**

utilize the `ItemTouchHelper` class drag functionality and attach it to the `RecyclerView` using `attachToRecyclerView()` method

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Item> mItems;
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        populateItems();

        mAdapter = new Adapter(mItems);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP |
                        ItemTouchHelper.DOWN |
                        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT |
                        ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT,
                0) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                moveItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            }
        });

        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    private void populateItems() {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mItems.add(new Item("Android", R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Archive", R.drawable.ic_archive_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Alarm", R.drawable.ic_access_alarm_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Block", R.drawable.ic_block_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("CAll", R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Android", R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Archive", R.drawable.ic_archive_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Alarm", R.drawable.ic_access_alarm_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("Block", R.drawable.ic_block_black_24dp));
        mItems.add(new Item("CAll", R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp));
    }

    private void moveItem(int oldPos, int newPos) {
        Item temp = mItems.get(oldPos);
        mItems.set(oldPos, mItems.get(newPos));
        mItems.set(newPos, temp);
        mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(oldPos, newPos);
    }

}
```

And here the result

[image]

wish that satisfy your needs